# Yii framework and file upload progress

Tags: php, yii

I googled and saw that there are some plugins that do this. But would not want to use plugin because my only problem is this. Through Yii is possible in the session variable to obtain data regarding the progress of uploading a file?I'm making a system that uses php and Yii framework. I'm building a module to upload files. Everything is working perfectly except the display of the progress bar.

I researched and found that the version of PHP 5.4 has the capability forward: Session Upload Progress (http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)

I enabled this setting in my php.ini. I am using File Upload plugin to assist in the client side to perform file uploads. (github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

I want to run the following code:

Client side:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsend', function(e, data) {
            // This feature is only useful for browsers which rely on the iframe transport:
            if (data.dataType.substr(0, 6) === 'iframe') {
                // Set PHP's session.upload_progress.name value:
                var progressObj = {
                    name : 'PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS',
                    value : (new Date()).getTime()
                // pseudo unique ID
                };
                data.formData.push(progressObj);
                // Start the progress polling:
                data.context.data('interval', setInterval(function() {
                    $.get(yii.baseUrl + '/atl/default/progressUpload', $.param([progressObj]), function(result) {
                        // Trigger a fileupload progress event,
                        // using the result as progress data:
                        e = $.Event('progress', {
                            bubbles : false,
                            cancelable : true
                        });
                        $.extend(e, result);
                        ($('#fileupload').data('blueimp-fileupload') || $('#fileupload').data('fileupload'))._onProgress(e, data);
                    }, 'json');
                }, 1000)); // poll every second
            }
        }).bind('fileuploadalways', function(e, data) {
            clearInterval(data.context.data('interval'));
        });

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType : 'json',
            axFileSize : 500000000,
            forceIframeTransport : true,
            add : function(e, data) {
                data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload').appendTo(document.body).click(function() {
                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                    data.submit();
                });
            },
            done : function(e, data) {
                alert("done!");
            },
            progressall : function(e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                console.log(e, data, progress);
                $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            }
        });
```

Server Side:

```
public function actionProgressUpload($PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS) {

        $s = Yii::app()->session['upload_progress_'.intval($PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS)];
        $progress = array(
                'lengthComputable' => true,
                'loaded' => $s['bytes_processed'],
                'total' => $s['content_length']
        );
        echo json_encode($progress);
    }
```

My problem:

Yii in the $ _SESSION variable always returns null, the variable Yii::app()->session does not return me the values ​​for upload progress.

I googled and saw that there are some plugins that do this. But would not want to use plugin because my only problem is this. Through Yii is possible in the session variable to obtain data regarding the progress of uploading a file?

Thanks.

Comment: You sure you initialized first your custom session 
`Yii::app()->session['upload_progress_'.intval($PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS)]` 

before you obtained its value?

Comment: The session is initialized automatically by Yii.

Comment: What I meant was is your `'upload_progress_' . intval(...)` session key was initialized?

Comment: This variable is set by PHP while uploading files. Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php

Comment: Read the one of the entries in User Contributed Notes: "don't forget, that the session has to be initialized before the form is generated, otherwise the mentioned example above won't work.", Are you really sure that it was initialized?

Comment: Also, "Note, this feature doesn't work, when your webserver is running PHP via FastCGI." Are you?

Comment: Looks like adding an upload plugin is a lot easier than pioneering this technique...

Comment: Actually my server is running PHP via FastCGI. Thanks. In the current system I'm doing I have chosen to not display the progress bar, but gets as information for future systems. About using a plugin most are not compatible with IE7 and IE8 displaying a progress bar.

Comment: @LeonardoDelfino can you tell me how to define the upload progress library? ex: use yii\web\session. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

protected/config/main.php

Check whether the session is set to false in `main config`. if it so then i wont work

`'session' => array (
    'autoStart' => false,
),`